# SpringBoot failed startup of jetty - something to do with springfox?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, springfox

I am getting the following exception when SpringBoot (release 1.5.7) is starting up. I don't remember changing anything but obviously something changed because this exception never happened before. Has anyone seen this? I have seen other posts that have a larger stack trace that gives more helpful information but I don't see that. Just this exception. It looks like it is pointing to an issue with the springfox-swagger-ui jar file but I am not sure where to go with that.

```
 2018-02-20 16:01:00.367  WARN 9476 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext   : Failed startup of context o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@2c2c3947{/invmgt/api/v1,[file:///C:/Users/u447/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-docbase.1736805776280533468.8080/, jar:file:/C:/Users/u447/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.7.0/92608eb6c2056810b4e3189196b4e8cce645d6de/springfox-swagger-ui-2.7.0.jar!/META-INF/resources],UNAVAILABLE}

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:229) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:89) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer.callInitializers(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:83) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer.doStart(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:72) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) [jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105) [jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) [jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:120) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:844) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1501) ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1463) ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545) ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) [jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452) [jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105) [jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) [jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419) [jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:104) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getJettyEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:561) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:190) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) [spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at clientletter.Application.main(Application.java:49) [bin/:na]
```

Comment: According to the stack trace, it fails in EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize where it goes through a list of ServletContextInitializer and calls .onStartup on each of them. Initializers are collected by ServletContextInitializerBeans. So, you can try to debug it. Maybe it can help.

Comment: I did as you suggested and debugged into selfInitialize(). At the end of that method there is a for block where it makes a call to getServletContextInitializerBeans() and for each one calls onStartup(). Unfortunately the getServletContextInitializerBeans() is returning null and the beans.onStartup() call is still made - NPE. Not sure where to go with that.

Comment: More information: getServletContextInitializerBeans() returns a ServletContextInitializerBeans object and its iterator is to a list whose first entry is null. Thus the NPE. Not sure yet why the first entry in the list is null.

Comment: Ok, it looks like the 'filterAuthorizationBean' has a null initializer. Does that ring a bell to anyone?